# AndEngine duration between animation

Tags: android, animation, sprite, andengine, duration

I am developing a simple game which is totally based on animation. For this app, I am using AndEngine  SDK. I am totally new in developing games in Android. I googled it lot, but all articles are so advanced and that are of no use for me in this app.

My Questions:

1.How can I perform loop animation with specific delay in each animation?

Here is my code:

```
final Sprite playButton = new Sprite(centerX, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 500, mPlayButton, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
final ScaleModifier scale = new ScaleModifier(0.5f, 1, 1.1f, 1f, 1.1f);
LoopEntityModifier scalePlayButton = new LoopEntityModifier(scale);
playButton.registerEntityModifier(scalePlayButton);
mScene.attachChild(playButton);
```

Now, I want specific delay in each scale animation performing in a loop.

2.If I don't use LoopEntityModifier, then how can I perform scale animation after specific delay. For this to achieve, here is my code:

```
final Sprite playButton = new Sprite(centerX, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 500, mPlayButton, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
final ScaleModifier scale = new ScaleModifier(0.5f, 1, 1.1f, 1f, 1.1f);

scale.addModifierListener(new IModifier.IModifierListener<IEntity>() {
      @Override
      public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity         pItem) {

      }
      @Override
      public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                 playButton.registerEntityModifier(scale);
      }
});

playButton.registerEntityModifier(scale);
mScene.attachChild(playButton);
```

But, it is not starting animation again once I attachChild to scene.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `DelayModifier` class with the combination of `SequenceEntityModifier` and `LoopEntityModifier` from AndEngine. Here is code snippet:

```
final Sprite playButton = new Sprite(centerX, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 500, mPlayButton, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
SequenceEntityModifier scaleSequence = new SequenceEntityModifier(
         new ScaleModifier(0.2f, 1f, 1.07f),
         new ScaleModifier(0.2f, 1.07f, 1f),
         new DelayModifier(2f)
 );
LoopEntityModifier scaleLoopModifier = new LoopEntityModifier(scaleSequence);
playButton.registerEntityModifier(scaleLoopModifier);
mScene.attachChild(playButton);
```

Hope it helps you!